# 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a definition for 'FileName'

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, directory, fileinfo

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GrdVw_Download">
                        <RowStyle cssclass="ItemStyle" />
                        <HeaderStyle cssclass="tableheader" horizontalalign="Left" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle cssclass="AlternateItemStyle" horizontalalign="Left" />
                        <FooterStyle backcolor="#5D7B9D" font-bold="True" forecolor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField headertext="File name" headerstyle-horizontalalign="Center" itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center"
                                datafield="FileName" />
                            <asp:BoundField headertext="File Size" headerstyle-horizontalalign="Center" itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center"
                                dataformatstring="{0:#,### bytes}" datafield="Length" />
                            <asp:BoundField headertext="Extension" headerstyle-horizontalalign="Center" itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center"
                                datafield="Extension" />
                            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Download Brochure" itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center"
                                headerstyle-horizontalalign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href="?dl=<%# Encryptor.encrypt(((FileInfo)Container.DataItem).FullName) %>" 
                                    title="Download <%# ((FileInfo)Container.DataItem).FileName %>">
                                        <%# ((FileInfo)Container.DataItem).FileName %>
                                    </a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

that's my gridview markup and below is the databinding part

```
    DirectoryInfo ProviderFolder = new DirectoryInfo(strFolderPath);
    FileInfo[] BrochureList = ProviderFolder.GetFiles();
    if (BrochureList.Length > 0)
    {
        GrdVw_Download.DataSource = BrochureList;
        GrdVw_Download.DataBind();
    }
```

in the gridview in this line `<a href="?dl=<%# Encyptor.encrypt(((FileInfo)Container.DataItem).FullName)` i get the error the post talks about. Where Encryptor encrypts the FilePath and markup generates a link to download the file
**Edit Sorry:**
**Solved it.** It is not FileName but just Name.Sorry again

Comment: Instead of adding "[Solved]" to the question title you should accept the answer that actually solved your problem.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the information. I would have accepted an answer is he had posted the solution before i had updated. While i was updating the Question with mistake i had made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because **'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a definition for 'FileName'**

Are you looking for `FullName` or `Name` perhaps?

Comment: you must have posted this when i was updating. I updated my original post